# How to access Class variable in manifest file

Tags: android, authentication, android-manifest, manifest

I am implementing a facebook authentication in my android application.
I want to access API key from my java class. I have this implementation in menifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

For some purpose I dont want to keep app_id in strings.xml file, rather I want to keep it in java file encoded/encrypted so in run time I decrypt/decode the app_id and make a login request. 
I didnt find a way to get java variable in manifest file. 
Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: As I know you can't accomplish this because AndroidManifest doesn't support such functionality, but try to look at manifest merger (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).